# unable to create table in dynamodb-local - aws

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm using [dynamoDB-local](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Tools.DynamoDBLocal.html) with nodejs code.

I have the following code:

```
var aws = require("aws-sdk")
aws.config.update({"accessKeyId": "aaa",
                   "secretAccessKey": "bbb",
                   "region": "us-east-1"})

var awsdb = new aws.DynamoDB({ endpoint: new aws.Endpoint("http://localhost:8000") });

awsdb.createTable({
  TableName: 'myTbl',
  AttributeDefinitions: [
    { AttributeName: 'aaa', AttributeType: 'S' },
  ],
  KeySchema:[
    { AttributeName: 'aaa', KeyType: 'HASH' }
  ]
}, function() { 
    awsdb.listTables(function(err, data) {
      console.log(data)
  });
});
```

But it isn't creating the table. I'm getting `{ TableNames: [] }` in logs.
err is null.

Comment: `createTable` will return `{ TableNames: [] }` if this has been set in your code: `::Aws.config[:stub_responses] = true` (that is Ruby but you get the point)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you are missing the required ProvisionedThroughput parameter in the CreateTable request. So what is happening is the CreateTable returns a validation error and ListTables executes successfully without returning any tables (The "err" variable in your code seems to be for the ListTables call)

E.g. the following is working for me

```
var aws = require("aws-sdk")
aws.config.update({"accessKeyId": "aaa",
  "secretAccessKey": "bbb",
  "region": "us-east-1"})
var awsdb = new aws.DynamoDB({ endpoint: new aws.Endpoint("http://localhost:8000") });

awsdb.createTable({
  TableName: 'myTbl',
  AttributeDefinitions: [
       { AttributeName: 'aaa', AttributeType: 'S' },
       ],
  KeySchema:[
       { AttributeName: 'aaa', KeyType: 'HASH' }
  ],
  ProvisionedThroughput: {ReadCapacityUnits: 1, WriteCapacityUnits: 1},
}, function(err, data) {
  if (err) 
    console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else {
    awsdb.listTables(function(err, data) {
      console.log(data)
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I already tried the `ProvisionedThroughput` before. But I put there the `KeyType` as string - `S` - so it didn't work , that's why I removed it. Just after that I changed it to `HASH` but didn't return it :)

Answer (score 0):

After you issue a createTable you have to wait until the table is effectively created. Once the table is created it will appear in your listTables call. You can wait by using the describeTable call.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB.html#createTable-property

> CreateTable is an asynchronous operation. Upon receiving a CreateTable request, DynamoDB immediately returns a response with a TableStatus of CREATING.
>
> You can use the DescribeTable API to check the table status.

Comment: Just wanted to note that DynamoDB Local creates tables immediately so you can get away without doing this if you aren't working with the actual service.(Of course, it is recommended to do the check for TableStatus ACTIVE if you intend to use real DynamoDB eventually :) )